# How to configure sequence list items in Python

Tags: python

I tried to configure this sequencing list items in Python but I don't understand. How do i configure it ?

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "configure this sequencing list items". What do you try to achieve? What did you try so far? Can you give us an example of your code?

Comment: What you don't understand?

Comment: It appears you have it ordered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = [1,2,3,4]
l = len(ls)//2
a = ls[l:]  # 3,4 - Second last element,last element
b = ls[:l][::-1] # 2,1 - Second element,First element
c = a+b
print(c) # [3, 4, 2, 1]
```

But if the lenth of list is odd number, you have to change condition as per your need or please update question to meet your needs